# Django - How can users view books under his membership type?

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

I set up memberships for users so that they can have an option to view selected books under a certain membership type. In this case how can a user view the list of books under his membership type within his profile page?

Here are my codes for books:

`````
class Book(models.Model):
``` some book fields```

    activeReference = models.ManyToManyField(Membership) #here's where membership connects````
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
`````

Here are for the models for membership:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
     membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     price = models.IntegerField(default=100)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.membership_type

class Customer(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
      reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.user.email
```

And here's the view for profile:

````
def profile(request):
```some update profile post code here```

    context = {

        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
````

I expect for the user to view all his books under his membership type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{{ user.customer.membership.book_set.all }}
```

#### Explanation:

Here in template, you can access the `User` instance by `{{ user }}` if he/she is logged in. Then, you can access `customer` instance as it has [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation to `CustomerModel`. `membership` is FK to `Membership` model. Finally, you can access the book instances through [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) (`book_set`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there anyway that I can put it in a for loop so that the user can see it as a list connected to the absolute url of the book?

Comment: Sure `{% for book in user.customer.membership.book_set.all %} {{ book.get_absolute_url }} {% enfor %}`

Answer (score 2):

{{ user.customer.membership.book_set.all }}

Answer (score -2):

create new template file for show all books use ListView in view function and call template file as a template = 'template_name' and also import template

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the question at all.